# Run migrations from a Laravel dependency

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking to have multiple laravel projects. One that has my models and migrations. Let's call it my schema project. I will have several other projects with different frontends for different things. These other projects will use the schema project as a dependency. How should I go about running the migrations though? Should I simply cd to the schema project in the vendor directory and run artisan migrate?

Comment: Are you going to use the same models and migrations for all projects?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/is-laravel-54-running-migrations-from-vendor-folders-now offers options

Comment: There's even an official documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/packages#migrations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will have a crack at this. I come across an article with the same senario. Unfortunately i dont have the link to the original post. But as far as i remember, you can achieve this as folllows.

1)Hence all the other projects are depending on the schema project you will have to include this as dedependency in each composer.json of every other project. You need to add the project path to the
Composer.json.

2)then create a service provider in schema project and register your migrations within its `boot` method as follows. Replace it with the path to your migrations directory.

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/migrations');
```

3)lastly you need to run`composer update` within each dependent project to install the schema project.

4)once you done that, you sholud be able to run `php artisan migrate` within other dependent projects.